# Login into iCloud via Json Post request

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to log in into iCloud using a Json Post request in C#. Before trying to implement the code I was studying a little bit the iCloud requests using Chrome Console and using an Ad-on to replicate the requests in order to obtain the same result of the website.

First of All I checked the request directly from iCloud website:

[image]

And this is the response:

```
{
 "serviceErrors" : [ {
 "code" : "-20101",
 "message" : "Il tuo ID Apple o la password non sono corretti."
 } ]
}
```

Using "Advance REST Client" ad Chrome plugin to replicate the request I ve tried the same Json request to the same Url. But I get Empty response:
[image]

I Also tried to copy and paste the whole Header (All the settings) and than send the request but the response is the same:
[image]

Anyone has an Advice?

UPDATE: I tried to implement A Json request through c# program:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{accountName: \"briesanji @gmail.com\", password: \"testPassword\", rememberMe: false, trustTokens: []}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

The problem is that Execution breaks when the

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

is hit and it gives me this error: System.Net.WebException: 'Error Remote Server: (400) Request not valid.'

UPDATE: I solved in this way:

```
void POST(string url, string jsonContent)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";

        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(jsonContent);

        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.ContentType = @"application/json";

        using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }
        long length = 0;
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                length = response.ContentLength;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            // Log exception and throw as for GET example above
        }
    }

    string GET(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // log errorText
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Anyways I tested also the Answer and it was good to.. So I check it as valid thanks.

Comment: Why C# if you want a json request from chrome? Anyway, as far as I see you use exactly the same cookie-data and the same widgetKey in the chrome dump and the rest-client. I think you have to create one request to the original uri without the widget key and get the widgetKey and the cookie-data from this response - then you send your login-data to this new uri... **not tested**

Comment: Nono I want use C# code.. But As you can Read in the frist two lines of my post.. I just want to test how should set the Json request.. Anyway.. In my second ScreenShot I did what you say and I had no result.. in AnyCase I will update the post with the C# code as soon as possible.

Comment: In your second screenshot you send the login data without a widgetKey in the uri. And in your third screenshot you used the same target uri...

Comment: I used the same target Uri because the response was empty.. So I couldn't get the Widget Key. For this reason I tested Again with the same Uri trying to replicate the result of the original Login but with bad result. Now I m trying to send a request from a c# app. Even if I think that the result will be bad too

Comment: Well, the widgetKey seems to be constant - its same for me. Sadly i can't test this since i dont have an icloud account... But if you have a look at the initial request to icloud.com. Dont know where this request is send, but there is a request to the signin?widgetKey=... and you get a cookie in the response to this request. You might need this cookie if you try to authenticate...

Comment: mhh intrestring.. I will work around.. thanks for the help

Comment: Dont know if this makes a difference - but try to quote 'accountName', 'password' and so on... And this request does not have the mentioned cookie...

Comment: Tried.. Got the same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this i dont get any error and the response content of the second request just tells me that there were too many failed logins for the test account...

```
    private static void ICloud()
    {
        var cc = new CookieContainer();

        var first = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin?widgetKey=83545bf919730e51dbfba24e7e8a78d2&locale=de_DE&font=sf");
        first.Method = "GET";
        first.CookieContainer = cc;

        var response1 = (HttpWebResponse)first.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var second = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin");
        second.ContentType = "application/json";
        second.Method = "POST";
        second.Accept = "application/json";
        second.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
        second.Referrer = "https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin?widgetKey=83545bf919730e51dbfba24e7e8a78d2&locale=de_DE&font=sf";
        second.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        second.Headers.Add("X-Apple-Widget-Key", "83545bf919730e51dbfba24e7e8a78d2");

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(second.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"accountName\":\"test@icloud.com\",\"password\":\"test\",\"rememberMe\":false,\"trustTokens\":[]}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        try
        {
            var response2 = (HttpWebResponse)second.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch(WebException we)
        {
            using (var r = new StreamReader(we.Response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result2 = r.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get A long Html file as response too?

Comment: @Briesanji Yep. I got the hole html page of icloud.com... with the message that there were too many login attempts and that the account needs to be unlocked...

Comment: Mhhhh.. is the same message that I get when I try to log in with my real credential.. So the answer is almost correct but there is something that I m missing. (I tried to log in with my account on Icloud site and everything goes well)
I also get the same error using my email and inserting a wrong passord.. But I expect this response when the pwd is wrong: "{
 "serviceErrors" : [ {
 "code" : "-20101",
 "message" : "Il tuo ID Apple o la password non sono corretti."
 } ]
}"

Comment: @Briesanji I've modified my post - works for me... in the WebException response I have your desired JSON answer...

Comment: Oh Amazing.. So pratically the problem was simply the fact that there wasn't an Exception Handler that could detect that Status code.. And in that way the server always returned the HTML file.

Comment: @Briesanji No. The reason was that the accept header was set to allow every response type (*), including html. I changed that to only accept application/json as response type and then the server returned the 403 http error which causes the exception.

Comment: Great.. Very helpfull